# Why composition animation(example in UWP docs) is not working?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

The simple animation example show in the Windows UWP docs under the section of Visual Layer and sub-section of Time animation is not working...

[image: UWP docs animation code Image]

Above is the code example shown in the docs.
[image: XAML rectangle code]

Above is the code of XAML rectangle that I am animating.[image: C# code for animation]

Above is the code I have written, similar to the code in first image.[image: Error in debug mode]

Now this is the error I am getting every time I run the app in debug mode. The property was not found. But that is what is written in docs, then how could it be. One more thing I have tried setting the property to renderTransform as well but that doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding another answer because the one here isn't entirely correct - whilst the example *IS* wrong, there is in fact a `Translation` property on Composition Visuals that come from XAML objects - that is also most likely preferable to using offset if your animating a visual of a XAML object.

Firstly, you need to enable the translation property on the element like so:

`ElementCompositionPreview.SetIsTranslationEnabled(uiElement, true)`

Secondly, you then need to change the animation property to actually target the correct property:

`visual.StartAnimation("Translation.X", animation);`

*This only works if you're targeting the creators update or above.*

Using `Translation` over `Offset` entirely avoids issues where XAML layout updates break the animation - as XAML position updates will overwrite a Visual's Offset and stop any current animation, whereas Translation animations will continue to run unabated of what the XAML layout engine does.

Comment: Okay so just a simple question! How do I know what properties are available for an object to animate? It would be very helpful if there is some way of figuring out all the properties.

Comment: pnp0a03's link cover's most of them. There used to be a grerat Composition master documents on Microsoft's dev site, but it's been removed now. Translation is a special case property that's not properly documented anywhere - I'm not even sure if Microsoft's documentation site even mentions it at all!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/time-animations#example) is wrong. The Visual object have no properties like as "Translation".  To move it from left to right,

```
visual.StartAnimation("Offset.X", animation);
```

or

```
visual.StartAnimation(nameof(visual.Offset) + "." + nameof(visual.Offset.X), animation);
```

I have very simple example code of animate the object with UI.Composition on GitHub. The comments are all Japanese, but it may help you, I hope so.

[CompositionGridView](https://github.com/pnp0a03/CompositionGridView)

Comment: It worked like charm! Thanks. Can I ask for one more favor? I am learning about composition APIs from few days, is there any way I can see all the animateable properties for a UIElement, like Scale, Offset, or whatever there are?

Comment: You can find "Animatable Properties" from here  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Composition.Visual